# "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" recording audio with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to follow [this recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/record_audio/) to record audio with Xamarin. It is a Xamarin.Forms solution, but for now I'm only developing for Android. I have to say that I'm C#/.NET developer and this is my first contact with Android. I created "Services" folder in the MicTest.Droid project and I put there my service:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MicrophoneService))]
namespace MicTest.Droid.Services
{
    public class MicrophoneService : IMicrophoneService
    {
        public string FileName { get; private set; }
        public string FilePath { get { return Path.Combine("data", $"{this.FileName}.3gpp"); } }

        private MediaRecorder recorder;

        public MicrophoneService() { }

        public void StartRecording(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                this.FileName = fileName;
                //bool exist = Directory.Exists("data");

                this.recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                this.recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
                this.recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.ThreeGpp);
                this.recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
                this.recorder.SetOutputFile(this.FilePath);
                this.recorder.Prepare(); // It crashes here
                this.recorder.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public void StopRecording()
        {
            try
            {
                this.recorder.Stop();
                this.recorder.Reset();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IMicrophoneService interface is in the shared project:

```
namespace MicTest.Services
{
    public interface IMicrophoneService
    {
        void StartRecording(string fileName);
        void StopRecording();
    }
}
```

And this is the excetion:

```
data/2016-08-31 16.22.58.3gpp: open failed: EACCES(Permission denied)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11643 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:26 
  at Android.Media.MediaRecorder.Prepare() [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Media.MediaRecorder.cs:476 
  at MicTest.Droid.Services.MicrophoneService.StartRecording(System.String fileName) [0x0006f] in F:\Probak\Xamarin\MicTest\MicTest\MicTest.Droid\Services\MicrophoneService.cs:53       --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/2016-08-31 16.22.58.3gpp: open failed: EACCES(Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:117)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:149)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:750)
    at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4763)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19821)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES(Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
    ... 15 more
```

And finally, this is the manifest file (in the future I want to use location services):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="$safeprojectname$"></application>
</manifest>
```

I don't know if I can use "data" folder or not, I tryed with other folders like `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads` with the same result. Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving to your app's cache dir to valid your permissions:

```
var fileName = "audio.3gpp";
fileName = Path.Combine(Android.Content.Context.CacheDir.Path, fileName)
this.FileName = fileName;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but get this error wen I use `Android.Content.Context.CacheDir.Path`:
**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Context.CacheDir'**

Comment: Using `Android.App.Application.Context.CacheDir.Path` instead of `Android.Content.Context.CacheDir.Path` works (I don't know if there are the same thing), but now I get an `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException` in `this.recorder.Stop();` line.

Comment: @Jon `Android.App.Application.....` will work fine (did not notice this is a in a service thus you do not have a App Context available. As for are the `IllegalStateException` on `.Stop`, that means that the recording has not been started. Consult the MediaRecorder flow diagram @https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: debugging I'm sure that all steps run in order. First: `SetAudioSource()`, `SetOutputFormat()`, `SetAudioEncoder()`, `SetOutputFile()`, `Prepare()` and `Start()`. And some seconds later: `Stop()` and `Reset()`.